# Imacro script not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, imacros

Ive written the below script in through the iMacro browser but i cant get it to execute through the firefox extention.I have tried to rebuild the code through the firefox extention, however, it always falls over at "FRAME NAME="isolatedWorkArea"". I understand that the firefox imacro extention does not have all of the functions that the imacro browser has but i am unable to work out exactly why this script will not execute.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Imacro Browser V12.0.501.6698,
Firefox 52.8.0,
Imacro for firefox V9.0.3

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
'
SET !VAR0 "EPANOTICESRemedial{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}"
SET !VAR1 "EPANOTICESPC{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}"
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.epa.vic.gov.au/our-work/compliance-and-enforcement/remedial-notices-and-directions
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Search<SP>for<SP>a<SP>remedial<SP>notice
TAB T=2
FRAME NAME="isolatedWorkArea"
TAG POS=4 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://crm.epa.vic.gov.au/SAP/BC/BSP/SAP/ZTHTMLB_STYLES/nova_epa/images/down.gif
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:All
TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=TXT:Search
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=L:\Data\Victoria\EPA<SP>Pollution<SP>Notices\Daily<SP>Downloads FILE= {{!VAR0}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://crm.epa.vic.gov.au/SAP/BC/BSP/SAP/ZTHTMLB_STYLES/nova_epa/images/tableView/excel_download.gif
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.epa.vic.gov.au/our-work/compliance-and-enforcement/remedial-notices-and-directions
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Search<SP>for<SP>a<SP>PC<SP>PAN
TAB T=2
FRAME NAME="isolatedWorkArea"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:C7_W22_V23_V24_onlinetranstype_max_hits CONTENT=50
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:All
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:C7_W22_V23_V24_SEARCH_BTN
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=L:\Data\Victoria\EPA<SP>Pollution<SP>Notices\Daily<SP>Downloads FILE= {{!VAR1}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://crm.epa.vic.gov.au/SAP/BC/BSP/SAP/ZTHTMLB_STYLES/nova_epa/images/tableView/excel_download.gif
```